# XML Transformation failed : Expected Qname?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<appcmd>

<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="DefaultAppPool" PipelineMode="Integrated" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Stopped">

<add name="DefaultAppPool" queueLength="1000" autoStart="false" enable32BitAppOnWin64="false">

</add>

</APPPOOL>

</appcmd>
```

and I have written the below XSLT to convert the above xml into another xml,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/appcmd/APPPOOL">

<xsl:variable name="AppName" select="@APPPOOL.NAME"/>

<xsl:element name="{$AppName}">

    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="@APPPOOL.NAME"/></xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="PipelineMode"><xsl:value-of select="@PipelineMode"/>

    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="RuntimeVersion"><xsl:value-of select="@RuntimeVersion"/>

    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="state"><xsl:value-of select="@state"/></xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:copy-of select="add"/>

</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the below error at --> xsl:element name="{$AppName}"
XML Transformation failed : Expected Qname.

Please help Me

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is working perfectly without change of single character. So, its may be the XSLT processor pbm, Pls use the following link to check your code .

http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php.

Ps: whenever ask help , pls explain little bit clear like which processor u using and version of the same etc .
By
Rajamani M
NIC -OTC

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any reason why this should fail - unless your input data is different from that shown, and the content of @APPPOOL.NAME is not a valid XML name.